# What are the next forks of the Blockchain that have been announced?

Tags: blockchain-fork, soft-fork, project-fork

- What are the next forks of the Blockchain that have been announced?
- When will they occur?
- Where can you be kept updated?

Many thanks for the replies!

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the next forks of the Blockchain that have been announced?

Just to be clear, anyone can "announce a fork", but adoption and news of said fork depends on the market demand for the new coin. Most recently, Bitcoin was forked to create [Bitcoin Cash](https://www.bitcoincash.org/) (BCH).

[Bitcoin SegWit2x](https://medium.com/@DCGco/bitcoin-scaling-agreement-at-consensus-2017-133521fe9a77) (a bitcoin hard fork), Bitcoin gold (a bitcoin hard fork), and [Bitcoin ABC](https://www.bitcoinabc.org/) (a Bitcoin Cash hard fork) are upcoming hard forks. (note: Bitcoin SegWit2x may or may not result in a currency split, depending on how miner support plays out)

> When will they occur?

Bitcoin SegWit2x at block number 494,784 (no way of knowing exact date) and Bitcoin ABC on November 13th, 2017. Expect many more in the future!

> Where can you be kept updated?

Twitter, [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/btc/), or a google alert with keyword "Bitcoin" :)

**Previous Forks:**

1. Bitcoin Cash forked from Bitcoin on Aug 1st, 2017.
2. Bitcoin Gold forked from Bitcoin at block number 491,407